# Using veiw functions to overload Blockchain node

Tags: security, nodes, gas-limit

Question: What is stopping me from creating view function with heavy computation (infinite loop). Deploying it on Blockchain and then calling it just so I could overload a Blockchain node that receives that request.

ETH protects itself from DOS attacks by the fact you need to pay gas fee. However, the view function would not cost any gas. (It needs gas to run, but I would not be charged for it)

So technically, if I had enough Eth to pay for block gas limit, I should theoretically be able to cause issues to some Blockchain nodes and make them waste their computational power with no cost to myself.

Obviously, I am missing something here, so I would love if somebody could explain why this isn't a security issue.

Comment: Using a view function you are calling and attacking 1 node. It will not affect the network.

Comment: You don’t need gas or ether to call a view function, it is a normal rpc request that is enabled or disabled by a node and has nothing to do with block generation or validation. Miner nodes disable rpc calls

Comment: Additionally most of the node has a rate and time limit and does not provide data for free. Pay per use with fiat money

Comment: I don't understand why you say "if I had enough Eth to pay for block gas limit". Can you explain? If you create a function and call it with a call not a transaction, you don't need gas. What is the gas limit required for in your exemple?